# Convert db2 to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I convert this db2 code to SQL Server:

```
TRIM(LEADING '0'FROM SUBSTR(A.BCBUPE,5,2))
```

Original data:

```
201712
```

Expected data:

```
12
```

Comment: Poor sample data. Add a row where the leading 0 is trimmed as well. E.g. `201808` -> `8`.

Comment: And `201010` -> `10`.

Comment: SQL SEVER VERSION?

Comment: Is the value really a string?  It's not an integer?   *(And god forbid anyone would use a DATE to hold...a date)*

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
SELECT RIGHT('201712',2);
```

Comment: `TRIM(LEADING '0'` not needed?

Answer (score 0):

are you find below

```
select substring('201712',5,2) 
it will return 12
```

in case of remove 0 in 1st you could use

```
SELECT
Right(
SUBSTRING(A.BCBUPE, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', A.BCBUPE + ' '), LEN(A.BCBUPE)),2)
```

Comment: `TRIM(LEADING '0'` not needed?